# Воспроизвести аудио без доступа из Веб (html, php)

Tags: php, html, аудио, web-audio

В теге `<audio>` можно вставлять только аудофайлы доступные через Веб. Мои файлы хранятся не в папке веб-сервера. Допустим я могу сделать символьную ссылку на эти файлы, но как мне разрешить их проигрывать только через данный тег audio и только на определенных страницах без участия флеш?

```
<audio controls>  
    <source src='/var/lib/audio/test.wav' type='audio/wav'>  
    <b>Your browser does not support the audio tag.</b>
</audio>
```

Comment: Никак. Как только браузер получает доступ к аудио (в том числе через этот тег audio), пользователь автоматически получает доступ сделать с этим свежескачанным аудио абсолютно что угодно

Comment: То что пользователь получит доступ к этому файлу, это не страшно. Но важно чтобы другие не получили к этому файлу доступ. Т.е. чтобы файл не был доступ по прямой ссылке <https://mysite.com/test.wav>

Comment: Тогда сделайте ссылку вида `mysite.com/34rghGfQ/test.wav` чтобы никто не смог угадать набор случайных буковок

Comment: Это конечно не полноценная защита. Но можно пока так

Comment: Тогда выдайте пользователю логин и пароль и запрещайте доступ к файлу, пока пользователь не залогинится

Comment: Через логин/пароль я понимаю как защитить файлы скрипты, а вот аудиофайлы не в курсе. Да и вариант ссылки вида "34rghGfQ" все таки не подойдет. эту ссылку пользователь свободно увидит в исходном коде

Comment: Ну и что, что увидит? Вы же сами 2 часа назад написали, что если пользователь получит доступ к этому файлу, это не страшно. Противоречите сами себе?

Comment: Если авторизованный пользователь получит доступ к файлу принадлежащему ему, это нормально. А другие соответственно не должны иметь к нему доступ. Если например файлы будут храниться на mysite.com/DJdfs3nD/<userid>/file.wav То какой нибудь умник обязательно полезет ковырять.

Comment: И ничего толкового не наковыряет, потому что для каждой новой ссылки должен быть сгнерирован новый уникальный случайный набор букв и цифр. Так что пусть ковыряет сколько влезет — вероятность угадывания случайных символов крайне мала.

Comment: А как генерировать то эти случайные ссылки? Данные по записям у меня хранятся в БД. Файлы сохраняются так же в определенном порядке на диске. Менять данные в БД или переносить файлы в такие вот случайно сгенерированные папки возможности нет. Максимум, это символьную ссылку делать с места хранения в раздел веб-приложения

Comment: Сперва сгенерировать (в PHP хватает функций для работы со случайными данными), потом делать файл со сгенерированным именем, потом сохранять сгенерированный путь к файлу в БД. Если у вас уже есть «небезопасные» файлы, то придётся их перенести и записи в БД обновить (это не должно быть большой проблемой, скрипт на десяток-другой строчек написать за полчасика).

Comment: Если вы не хотите/не можете их переносить и хотите оставить ссылки как есть, то для доступа к файлам придётся изобретать свой прокси-скрипт на PHP, который будет проверять, какой пользователь авторизован, и передавать содержимое файлов полностью через себя после проверки, и всю раздачу файлов придётся вести через такой проверяющий скрипт, и это конечно же сильно замедлит работу сайта.